# Библиотека для криптографии и работы с большими числами

Tags: php, c++

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеки С/С++ или PHP для работы с большими числами и операций над ними, типичными в криптографии, т.е. нахождение остатка по модулю, генерации простых больших чисел, возведения в степень, нахождение обратного значения и т.д. Хотя вроде пока все операции. Нужно реализовать ЭЦП Рабина обязательно вручную. Или может подскажите как обойтись обычными типами.

Comment: Смотря на сколько большими. Если числа больше 9227000000( точное число не знаю ), то это уже потому невозможно, что стандартный домашний процессор не способен обрабатывать такие величины.

Comment: Это понятно, что больше, чем __int64 нельзя использовать, поэтому и нужны такие библиотеки, реализующие длинную арифметику))

Comment: Боже ты мой. @Asen, когда-же вас забанят-то уже?

PS Прошу прощенья, не сдержался :)

Comment: А что такое, @Ilya Pirogov ?

Comment: Дикие Процессоры работают с int128 и int256 ^,,,,^

Comment: @Asen, когда в подобном контексте говорят о **больших числах**, то речь идет как минимум о *сотнях*, а скорее о ***тысячах бит***. 

Стандартный "домашний процессор" действительно не может оперировать больше чем 64 битами. (Возможно немного вру, там могут быть команды арифметики для 128-бит XMM регистров)

Comment: Оффтопя. Слышал, с AVX,SIMD уже 256 бит (регистры YMM вместо XMM) за раз обрабатывает. У некоторых GPU шина 512 бит, вроде как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) скорее всего подойдет, можно поискать ее варианты для разных языков

Answer (score 1):

Поискал в гугле по ключевому слову Bignumber: [результат](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/lin/ipp/ippcp/ippcp_apb/apb_bignumber_class.html)